# Strange behavior of timeuuid comparison

Tags: cassandra, cql3, cassandra-2.0, cqlsh

I have Cassandra 2.x cluster with 3 nodes and the db scheme like this:

```
cqlsh> CREATE KEYSPACE test_ks WITH REPLICATION = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 3} AND durable_writes = true;
cqlsh> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_ks.test_cf (
   ...   time timeuuid,
   ...   user_id varchar,
   ...   info varchar,
   ...   PRIMARY KEY (time, user_id)
   ... ) WITH compression = {'sstable_compression': 'LZ4Compressor'} AND compaction = {'class': 'LeveledCompactionStrategy'};
```

Lets add some data (wait some time betweeb inserts):

```
cqlsh> INSERT INTO test_ks.test_cf (time, user_id, info) VALUES (now(), 'user1', 'pythonista');
cqlsh> INSERT INTO test_ks.test_cf (time, user_id, info) VALUES (now(), 'user1', 'mr. Haskell');
```

Lets look at our data:

```
cqlsh> SELECT dateOf(time), user_id, info FROM test_ks.test_cf;

 dateOf(time)             | user_id | info
--------------------------+---------+-------------
 2014-06-24 16:00:31+0700 |   user1 | mr. Haskell
 2014-06-24 15:59:32+0700 |   user1 |  pythonista

(2 rows)
```

I get some strange results while querying test_cf CF:

```
cqlsh> SELECT dateOf(time) FROM test_ks.test_cf WHERE user_id='user1' AND token(time) >= token(maxTimeuuid('2014-06-24 16:00:31+0700')) ALLOW FILTERING;

 dateOf(time)
--------------------------
 2014-06-24 15:59:32+0700

(1 rows)

cqlsh> SELECT dateOf(time) FROM test_ks.test_cf WHERE user_id='user1' AND token(time) >= token(maxTimeuuid('2014-06-24 16:00:32+0700')) ALLOW FILTERING;

 dateOf(time)
--------------------------
 2014-06-24 15:59:32+0700

(1 rows)

cqlsh> SELECT dateOf(time) FROM test_ks.test_cf WHERE user_id='user1' AND token(time) >= token(maxTimeuuid('2014-06-24 16:00:33+0700')) ALLOW FILTERING;

 dateOf(time)
--------------------------
 2014-06-24 16:00:31+0700
 2014-06-24 15:59:32+0700

(2 rows)
```

As you can see comparison gives the wrong results, although, `timeuuid` must not be greater than `maxTimeuuid` and must be greater than 'minTimeuuid' (for a same datetime, of course =) ). Could somebody explain to me this strange behavior?

TIA!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, your primary key is backwards—if you want to perform queries like this, your `CREATE TABLE` statement should look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_ks.test_cf (
  time timeuuid,
  user_id varchar,
  info varchar,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, time)
) WITH compression = {'sstable_compression': 'LZ4Compressor'}
  AND compaction = {'class': 'LeveledCompactionStrategy'};
```

That makes `user_id` the partition key and `time` the clustering column, which fits your query pattern.

With this change, you no longer need to use the `TOKEN` function, which is needed to make range queries over partition keys, but is meaningless for clustering columns (and generally does not correspond to semantic ordering of column values). Since `time` is now a clustering column, you just need to do a normal comparison:

```
SELECT dateOf(time)
FROM test_ks.test_cf
WHERE user_id='user1'
  AND time >= maxTimeuuid('2014-06-24 16:00:31+0700');
```

You can also drop the `ALLOW FILTERING`, since you're now doing a standard range slice rather than the token comparison, which required scanning all the rows and making the comparison.