# Query on timeuuid type does not return correct results via cql

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am attempting to perform a query using timeuuid to retrieve a result set.

Table is as such:

```
CREATE TABLE mds.arguments_by_id (
  argument_id timeuuid PRIMARY KEY,
  category text,
  title text
)
```

When I select the dateOf() for all of the data in the table, I get the following:

```
select dateOf(argument_id),argument_id from arguments_by_id ;

 dateOf(argument_id)      | argument_id
 -------------------------+--------------------------------------
 2014-12-29 13:50:07-0500 | 81f990c0-8f8b-11e4-abb3-5d7a44c0d8a8
 2014-12-29 14:01:43-0500 | 20def1c0-8f8d-11e4-abb3-5d7a44c0d8a8
 2014-12-29 14:01:58-0500 | 29b50f50-8f8d-11e4-abb3-5d7a44c0d8a8
 2014-12-29 14:03:01-0500 | 4f6b72c0-8f8d-11e4-bc90-abc65998337a

(4 rows)
```

The query I'd like to run needs to return results where the argument_id (date) is greater than a specified date:

```
select dateOf(argument_id),argument_id from arguments_by_id where token(argument_id) > token(maxTimeuuid('2014-12-28 15:31:00-0500'));
```

However that query returns a (seemingly) incomplete result set when compared to the previous select:

```
 dateOf(argument_id)      | argument_id
--------------------------+--------------------------------------
 2014-12-29 14:01:43-0500 | 20def1c0-8f8d-11e4-abb3-5d7a44c0d8a8
 2014-12-29 14:01:58-0500 | 29b50f50-8f8d-11e4-abb3-5d7a44c0d8a8
 2014-12-29 14:03:01-0500 | 4f6b72c0-8f8d-11e4-bc90-abc65998337a

(3 rows)
```

My goal was to minimize the number of keys - but am wondering if I am 1) incurring a performance hit by going this route and 2) trying to do too much with the primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use a timeuuid column like this, you would need to make it a clustering column rather than a partition key ([docs](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_compound_keys_c.html)). You would need to adapt this to fit your data model, but here's an example:

```
create table sample (
  id int,
  tid timeuuid,
  category text,
  title text,
  primary key (id, tid)
);
```

Now we can do a few inserts a couple seconds apart:

```
insert into sample (id, tid) values (100, now());
insert into sample (id, tid) values (100, now());
insert into sample (id, tid) values (100, now());
insert into sample (id, tid) values (100, now());
```

Show all values:

```
select id,tid,dateOf(tid) from sample;

 id  | tid                                  | dateOf(tid)
-----+--------------------------------------+--------------------------
 100 | df4387a0-8fa8-11e4-bd3a-97fb52c7ef8c | 2014-12-29 14:20:19-0800
 100 | e085a490-8fa8-11e4-bd3a-97fb52c7ef8c | 2014-12-29 14:20:21-0800
 100 | e2bd6c20-8fa8-11e4-bd3a-97fb52c7ef8c | 2014-12-29 14:20:24-0800
 100 | e475f190-8fa8-11e4-bd3a-97fb52c7ef8c | 2014-12-29 14:20:27-0800
```

Show just a portion using timeuuid comparison:

```
select id,tid,dateOf(tid) from sample where id=100 and tid>=minTimeuuid('2014-12-29 14:20:24-0800');

 id  | tid                                  | dateOf(tid)
-----+--------------------------------------+--------------------------
 100 | e2bd6c20-8fa8-11e4-bd3a-97fb52c7ef8c | 2014-12-29 14:20:24-0800
 100 | e475f190-8fa8-11e4-bd3a-97fb52c7ef8c | 2014-12-29 14:20:27-0800
```

Note if you try a select without specifying the primary key (id=100), you'll get a warning that ALLOW FILTERING would be required for that query. This is generally the wrong thing to do as it will need to do a full table scan:

```
select id,tid,dateOf(tid) from sample where tid>=minTimeuuid('2014-12-29 14:20:24-0800');
Bad Request: Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and thus may have unpredictable performance. If you want to execute this 
query despite the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING
```

Here's another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24388154/9965) with a similar situation.

Comment: Thanks - I'll rework the data model.  I had a feeling the table scan would be an issue.